# How might I avoid opening a new window in due to watch results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

> Please, look into my code. I would like to avoid opening a new window in due to watching results. I would like to avoid showing results instead of current content in the same window.
>
> I have thought about using AJAX to show results in Dialog window (JQueryUI)
> https://jqueryui.com/dialog/
> but I have no idea how? Thank You in advance :)

**HTML: result_browser.html**

```
<form class="form" method="post" id="resultbrowserform">

    <!--Something-->

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Apply </button>
</form>

<div id="dialog" title="Details">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () { function serializeForm(form){...}

...

$('#resultbrowserform').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
            url: '/result_browser/data/',
            data:  serializeForm($('#resultbrowserform')),
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                $('#resultbrowsertablecontainer').remove();
                data = data.data;
                if (!data.length) {
                    window.alert('No data for selected time period');
                    return;
                }

                div = $('<div id="resultbrowsertablecontainer">');
                table = $('<table class="table table-striped">');
                header = $('<thead>');
                header.append($('<tr>')
                    .append( $('<th>').html('Die Id'))
                    .append( $('<th>').html('Application'))
                    .append( $('<th>').html('Result'))
                table.append(header);
                body = $('<tbody>');
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    row = $('<tr>');
                    row.append( $('<td>').html(data[i].die_id));
                    row.append( $('<td>').html(data[i].application));
                    row.append( $('<td>').html(data[i].result));

                    <!--I would like to avoid opening a new window-->
                    link = $('<a>').attr('target', '_blank').attr('href', '/result_details/' + data[i].result_id + '/').html('Details');

                    row.append($('<td>').append(link));
                    body.append(row);
                }
                table.append(body);
                div.append(table);
                $('#resultbrowsercontainer').append(div);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Simply remove this should do it: `.attr('target', '_blank')`

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the target attribute and then it will open inside itself:

```
<!--I would like to avoid opening a new window-->
link = $('<a>').attr('href', '/result_details/' + data[i].result_id + '/').html('Details');
```

Comment: I would like to avoid showing results instead of current content in the same window :)

Comment: Ok, so what exactly do you want to happen? It's not very clear

Comment: I recommend you edit the question and choose which option you want

Comment: I want to show results in a dialog window: jqueryui.com/dialog